# LinearLayout with RecyclerView hide ImageView on scroll outside CardView

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-recyclerview, imageview

I am trying to make an activity with a recyclerview inside a cardview. Above the cardview there's an image that I want it to disappear when I scroll the recyclerview but without make the light blue box disappear. How can I do this?
I tried with NestedScrollView but without results

[Actual layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPMSh.png)

Here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:transitionName="itemMainTransition"
          tools:context=".activity.WeatherActivity">
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/meteoTrentinoBanner"
                  android:background="#42a4ce"
                  android:src="@drawable/logo_meteotn"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

              <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                  android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                  app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                  app:cardElevation="5dp"
                  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="55dp"
                     android:orientation="horizontal"
                     android:background="@drawable/weather_border">

                     <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/backDay"
                         android:layout_width="70dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:src="@drawable/ic_back"/>
                     <LinearLayout
                         android:layout_width="0dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:layout_weight="1"
                         android:orientation="horizontal">
                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/textViewMinTemp"
                             android:layout_width="40dp"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                             android:textAlignment="center"
                             android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                             android:textSize="19sp"
                             android:textStyle="bold"
                             android:textColor="#0000FF"/>
                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
                             android:text="@string/oggi"
                             android:layout_width="0dp"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                             android:layout_weight="1"
                             android:gravity="center_vertical"
                             android:textAlignment="center"
                             android:textSize="25sp"
                             android:textStyle="bold"
                             tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/textViewMaxTemp"
                             android:layout_width="40dp"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                             android:textAlignment="center"
                             android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                             android:textSize="19sp"
                             android:textStyle="bold"
                             android:textColor="#FF0000"/>
                     </LinearLayout>

                     <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/forwardDay"
                         android:layout_width="70dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:src="@drawable/ic_forward"/>
                 </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="55dp"
                     android:orientation="horizontal"
                     android:background="@drawable/weather_border">
                     <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/meteoInfo"
                         android:layout_width="40dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:src="@drawable/ic_info"/>

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/textViewWeather"
                         android:textSize="23sp"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:singleLine="true"
                         android:ellipsize="marquee"
                         android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                         android:focusable="true"
                         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                         android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
                 </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMeteo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: your recycler view should scroll  over the bule box or not ?

Comment: no, the blue box should be always visible, the image should disappear while scrolling the recyclerview. the cardview should translate to top, hiding the image

Comment: what is the behaviour now?

Comment: at the moment the image and the box are fixed and only the recyclerview scrolls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".LeaveActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/resView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: that's better but the light blue box with the arrows still disappear. How can I fix it to top while scrolling and keep scroll only the recyclerview? Here is the screens of the current behaviour
https://imgur.com/a/dSW30NJ
https://imgur.com/a/OMgGsDK
https://imgur.com/a/kvYYzGT

Comment: Ok I have edited the answer check it and let me know

Comment: This is working perfectly now, Thank you so much, this is my accepted answer